# How do I get intellisense to work with VS Code when writing Typescript with imported 3rd party JS modules?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have the following import in my typescript file

```
import interactjs = require('http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.6/interact.min.js');
```

I also have interact.d.ts in a relative path ../../../typings/interactjs/interact.d.js, how do I make typescript type check against the type declaration?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference in your script file the definition file of your import :

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/interactjs/interact.d.js" />
```

Comment: When VS Code first shipped this was the way to do it. See my answer above for the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your tsd files in `jsconfig.json`. See [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) for details.

Summarized below for history and ease of reference.

> With the introduction of jsconfig.json, you no longer need to use /// references in each file (these were required in the initial versions of VS Code). As the file set is defined in jsconfig.json, VS Code knows what files and symbols are part of your project.
>
> As an example, you can just drop a new type definition .d.ts file into your project folder and VS Code will pick it up automatically.

```
{
  "files": [
      "app.js",
      "typings/node/dode.d.ts"
  ]
}
```